# Get the root element with filtered children

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

For the following Xml:

```
<A>
  <B id=1>
    <C id=2 />
  </B>
  <B id=3>
    <C id=4 />
  </B>
</A>
```

I want to get this results by having Id value 4 for C:

```
<A>
  <B id=3>
    <C id=4 />
  </B>
</A>
```

So, what is the best solution?

Comment: So, you want to get element `B` whose child `C`'s `id` is `4`?

Comment: Is the structure always the same?  The Tagnames? What about a `<B id=4>` ?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk :I want A with filtered children

Comment: @Henk Holterman: yes, I need to define C_id value and get A with filtered children.

Comment: it's easier using SQL XQuery.modify('delete(//*[not(descendant-or-self::B[@id=3]) and descendant::B] )') !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) representing your XML structure

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<A>
  <B id='1'>
    <C id='2' />
  </B>
  <B id='3'>
    <C id='4' />
  </B>
</A>");
```

and an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) representing the element with `id='4'` in that document

```
XElement x = doc.Descendants().Single(e => (int?)e.Attribute("id") == 4);
```

you can construct a new [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) consisting of that element and its parent elements as follows:

```
XElement y = x;

while (x.Parent != null)
{
    x = x.Parent;
    y = new XElement(x.Name, x.Attributes(), y);
}

XDocument result = new XDocument(y);
```

*Result:*

```xml
<A>
  <B id="3">
    <C id="4" />
  </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<A>
<B id='1'>
<C id='2' />
</B>
<B id='3'>
<C id='4' />
</B>
</A>");

var elementsToRemove = doc.Root.Elements("B")
    .Where(b => (int)b.Element("C").Attribute("id") != 4);

elementsToRemove.Remove();

Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Output:

```
<A>
  <B id="3">
    <C id="4" />
  </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, this is what you want:

```
//*[descendant::C[@id=4]]
```

i.e. all elements which have `<c id="4"/>` as a child.

Btw, your XML should have quotes around the numbers to be well-formed.

Comment: This solution doesn't prune unwanted elements!

Comment: It should - can you try it in e.g. this xpath tester: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm. It will filter to what you gave as an example (i.e. A with B[@id=3] under it and then C[@id=4] under B). Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I need to have element A & remove unwanted B from its children. Two other ans do what I want. but the ideal is just to use XPath!

Comment: Can you try it in some online xpath tester to confirm it returns what you want? Try any - e.g. here's another one you can try - http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx. When I enter your XML and my xpath selector, A and B of `<c id="4"/>` get selected and nothing else. If you use `descendant-or-self`, you will get A, B and C.

Comment: No,this doesn't return what I want. this XPath returns element A with all its children + element B[@id=4]. but I want element A with child  B[@id=4] , no one else as it child.

Comment: Is it possible just using XPath?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. I don't think that's possible. XPath is a selection language - it allows you to precisely select nodes, but not transform them. E.g. you cannot say "give me a node and only it's 5th child". You can select 5th child itself. To do transformations, you need to use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt), but given you are using C#, the other answers might be more suitable then introducing XSLT into the picture.